# How to set the width of a Single Rich Text Editor field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Sharepoint 2016 On Prem:

**My form has multiple rich text editor fields but I only want to change the width of one of them**.

I know how to do it using css or script for ALL rich text editor fields, but I can't figure out how to do it for only 1 of them.

This css entry updates all the rte's:

```
.ms-rtestate-write{
    width:1000px;
}
```

And this script does all the rte's as well:

```
$('.ms-rtestate-write').css("width","700px");
```

I'm sure I must have to reference the id of the field I want to update but I found multiple id's and I don't know which one to use or the right syntax.

Which of these id's should I use?

```
Body_2a4c2989-39fe-44db-a783-3559dc47ddea_$TextField_inplacerte
Body_2a4c2989-39fe-44db-a783-3559dc47ddea_$TextField_topDiv
Body_2a4c2989-39fe-44db-a783-3559dc47ddea_$TextField_inplacerte_label
```

This will change the field I want but it also updates the other rte fields:

```
document.getElementById('Body_2a4c2989-39fe-44db-a783-3559dc47ddea_$TextField_inplacerte').style.width='1000px';
```

How can I do this to affect only my one field?  I think I'm close but I can't figure out the right combination. I'd prefer to do it with css but I'm ok with either option.

Thank you

EDIT:

JoannaW's suggestion worked.  The key is that you need to reduce the width of the other rte fields individually.

My final code:

```
//increase the width of the Body of Email field
$('div[id="Body_2a4c2989-39fe-44db-a783-3559dc47ddea_$TextField_topDiv"]').css('width','1000px');
// reduce the width other rich text fields
$('div[id="Purpose_b9fb03fb-d16a-435f-bf51-0cfc0a47e95c_$TextField_topDiv"]').css('width','350px');
```

Comment: Could you not open the form in InfoPath and then set the particular width on that field using Field Properties?

Comment: I'm not using infopath and it's not a custom form.  Just a basic form but I need to make minor adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are put in a table.

Try using the following scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {   
    // change the td width
    $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("rich01")').closest('td').next('td')[0].width='1000px';
    // reduce the width other rich text fields
    $('div[id="rich02_3ed196b8-bcfc-4f8c-b2f2-e87fb291651d_$TextField_topDiv"]').css('width','350px')           
}, false); 
</script>
```

The testing results:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I'm not sure why you added the event listener as I put mine under $(document).ready and it works the same. I guess the key is that you need to reduce the size of the other fields.

Comment: You say tomato..., DOMContentLoaded and $(document).ready are both adding an event listener, it's just that which event listener is abstracted away from you with $(document).ready. And on a modern browser, they're the same, but DOMContentLoaded may not be supported by older browsers. https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/